# PHP CRUD data not posting even after db connection successful

Tags: php, sql, crud

I developed the create function for my PHP CRUD, the database connection is successful, but when I post the data, it doesn't do anything. It should either say that the data is posted successfully or that there is an error.

I have two pages:

connect.php:

```
<?php 
$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'crudoperation');

if(!$con){
    die(mysqli_error($con));
}else{
    echo 'database connection successfully established';
}
?>
```

and user.php

```
<?php 
include 'connect.php';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){ // si on appuye sur submit, poster tous les champs
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];

    $sql="insert into `crud` (name, email, mobile, password)
    values('$name','$email','$mobile','$password')";
    $result=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if($result){
        echo "Data inserted successfully";
    }else{
        die(mysqli_error($con));
    }
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>CRUD PHP</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container my-5">
        <form method="post">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your name" name="name" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your email" name="email" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label>Mobile</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your mobile number" name="mobile" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your password" name="password" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0pUGZvbkm6XF6gxjEnlmuGrJXVbNuzT9qBBavbLwCsOGabYfZo0T0to5eqruptLy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What can be the problem ?

I removed the `name="submit"` I previously had and instead of showing me a white screen, it showed me the same forms as before submitting.

Comment: Why did you remove the `name="submit"` attribute? Now you don't have any form field with the name `submit`, so `$_POST['submit']` will never be set (or have a value).

Comment: You might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-can-i-get-useful-error-messages-in-php  on how to display error messages from PHP.

Comment: because it shows me a blank page so I tried to remove it but now I know it's related to the `$_POST['submit']`

Comment: You might also want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php on how to use SQL queries with variables.

Comment: And also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-phps-password-hash-to-hash-and-verify-passwords on how to store passwords in a database.

Comment: good point progman

Comment: Also check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/14868997 for why never to use `or die()` on errors, because of lack of proper cleanup.

Comment: @Amaury: *”it showed me the same forms as before submitting”* - This is expected behavior when the very first if statement in the code shown is false, which it always is since the form has no element with that name.  Removing the submit name resulted in this behavior.  You’ll want to put that back, and then diagnose the previous problem.  Turn on error reporting, add error handling, check PHP logs, debug the code, etc.  But for the problem presented here, the change you made is what caused it.

Comment: Thanks Progman and David, I resolved my issue

Comment: @Amaury You might want to post an answer so others can learn from the same mistake/error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my mistake was that I didn't activate the error reporting.
To activate it:

You have to create a file you open in the code editor and call it info.php
inside, add:

```
<?php

phpinfo();
```

you'll see a page with the php version and a table with information.
do a cmd f on mac or ctrl f on windows and search `Loaded Configuration File`. You'll find as the value of it, a path with the php.ini file. Find it in your directory and open the file with your favorite code editor.
once inside, we want to edit the file at two places. First search with cmd f on mac/ctrl f on windows error_reporting and make sure `error_reporting = E_ALL`. If not, replace it with the correct value.
Then search with cmd f on mac/ctrl f on windows for display_errors and make sure display_errors = On. If not, replace it with the correct value. Then restart MAMP/XAMP/WAMP.

Now you need to make a mistake so in the info.php file, replace the code by this one:

```
<?php

phpinfo(;
```

and once you visualise, you'll see the error appear.

In my case the error was that the database password was empty whereas there needed to be a password. I found the old password and entered it, which solved the issue.